# Background scrolls to top when i open Modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I use uibmodal in my app. The problem is that when i open it, my body scrolls to the top. The downside of this is if the modal is canceled or confirmed, the user is back at the top of the application. How do i make the body stay at the excact same position?

```
ctrl.openModal = function(ord, line) {
  var modal = $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    backdrop: "static",
    keyboard: false,
    resolve: {
      orderline: function() {
        return line;
      },
      order: function() {
        return ord;
      }
    },

    template: $templateCache.get("tpl/temp.html")[1],
    controller: "ControllerModal"
  });

  modal.result.then(
    function() {

      if (line.free3 != 0) {
        console.log("");
      } else {
        var payload = {

        };

      }
    },
    function() {
      //finish();
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: Where do you call this code? Can you post that part as well?

Comment: well, it's called directly from template. I will update the method so its in full